# How to make a 3D surface plot from DataSet

Tags: plotting, interpolation, dataset

I am trying to plot some Aerodynamic data.

I import my data like this:

data = SemanticImport["roll-damp-due-to-roll-rate-semantic.csv"]

The CSV file can be found here: [data](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B49qitQsNy34bmFlUF9fc1VIZUU&export=download)

[image: Output]

I want to make a 3D surface plot with that data. Alpha Column should be X-axis, -10 column should be located on -10 of Y-axis, 0 column on 0 of Y-axis, -10 on -10 on Y-axis. The data should be on Z axis. And data inbetween should be interpolated.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following `da` was the data imported using `Import`.`data`: removed headers of `da`; `dat` is transforming data into cartesian points.

```
dat = Catenate[{{#1, -10, #2}, {#1, 0, #3}, {#1, 10, #4}} & @@@ data];
Show[ListPlot3D[dat, ImageSize -> 300, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 15, Bold] & /@ {"\[Alpha]", "y", "z"}), 
  Mesh -> False], Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[dat]}]]
```

[image]

The red points are the data.

If I have misunderstood, my apologies.

Comment: As you said, by importing the data using Import[] instead of ImportSemantic and removing the header in the CSV file, your answer worked perfectly.

Thank you so much.

Comment: @Invariant37 thank you. I am glad it was helpful. I do not have any experience with `SemanticImport`. Others may provide answers dealing with that.  Good luck. :)

Comment: @ubpdqn You here again. I am happy to know that you are always ready to help everyone on this site. Congratulations.